# Git not storing symlink as a symlink on Windows

Tags: git

I have a project that contains three top-level directories:

```
A
B/dir1
C/symlink_to_dir1
```

As you can see, we're symlinking from a directory in C to another in B. These three directories are stored in a single Git repository on Windows, but we're having a problem when we try to commit the symlink. It was my understanding that Git would store the symlink as just that, and unpack it as a symlink in any repo this one was cloned into.

However, when we stage the symlink, it's the files in dir1 themselves that are added instead of the link itself. When we make the commit, `git status` will tell us the working directory is clean but `git add -A` will delete all the files from the symlinked directory and tell us that the symlink is untracked. This happens immediately after we make the commit, without any actions having taken place.

Our desire is to preserve the symlink so we don;t have to restore it each time we clone the repository, and it was my understanding that this was the default behaviour in Git. Can anyone please tell me what we're doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [Git for Windows based on msysgit](http://msysgit.github.com/), then the answer simply is that symbolic links (as introduced by Windows Vista) are not supported, even if core.symlinks is set to true. For reference, you may want to look at [this discussion](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=224), but please keep in mind that the issue tracker on Google Code is closed (in favor of the one at GitHub).

However, there seems to be [a fork that implements symlink support](https://github.com/frogonwheels/git/commits/mrg/unicode-symlink-v9), but that work has not yet been merged into msysgit.